# Group by with join and subquery cannot see parent table alias

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a question / answer panel.

Tables:

- users - typical with id, name, etc...,
- Replies - user's replies,
- Ratings - another user's ratings (1 or -1) related to a reply, every rating got a row

I need to get one row per user with related table having only 1 row for each user who rated his answer once. He got 20 points for each one. I also need when the rater sent 2 or more ratings for 60 points (not included in example) , but if I have solution I can extend it.
Problem with the following query: subquery cant see "user" alias, it says user.id is not found. 
Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT user.*, (
        SELECT COUNT(*) * 20
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM(rating_value) AS rv
            FROM Ratings
            LEFT JOIN Replies ON Replies.id = Ratings.replyId
            WHERE rating_value > 0
                AND Replies.userId = user.id
            GROUP BY Ratings.userId
            HAVING (rv = 1)
            ) ss
        ) AS points
FROM users user
```

Comment: `USER` is a reserved keyword (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), try changing it. But that's probably not what's causing the issue because you aren't joining users in your subquery

Comment: Tried another, that's not the problem :(

Comment: If you can provide a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with a schema and sample data we can help provide an answer.